# linux redirect last line of dwdiff result to a file

Tags: linux, shell

I am trying to create a sh that generates a report that will display differences against files from two folders/java projects. I am using [dwdiff](http://linux.die.net/man/1/dwdiff), and I need only the last line from each comparison (I don't care about differences, the percentage is what I need). I've created the following script:

```
DEST_FOLDER='./target/'
CLASSES_P1='classesP1.txt'
CLASSES_P2='classesP2.txt'
DEST_FILE='report.txt'

rm -r "$DEST_FOLDER"
mkdir -p "$DEST_FOLDER"

rm -f "$DEST_FOLDER/$CLASSES_P1"
rm -f "$DEST_FOLDER/$CLASSES_P2"
rm -f "$DEST_FOLDER/$DEST_FILE"

find ./p1 -name "*.java" >> "$DEST_FOLDER/$CLASSES_P1"
find ./p2 -name "*.java" >> "$DEST_FOLDER/$CLASSES_P2"

while read p; do
        while read t; do
                dwdiff -s $p $t | tail --lines=0 >> "$DEST_FOLDER/$DEST_FILE"
        done < $DEST_FOLDER/$CLASSES_P2

done < $DEST_FOLDER/$CLASSES_P1
```

It works fine, but the results are not redirected to the given file. The file is created, but is empty, and the last line from each dwdiff result is displayed to console. Any ideas?

Comment: `--lines=0` means the last 0 lines will be printed. Use `--lines=1`.

Comment: Or the short version `tail -n1`

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things going on

- The output you want is going to `stderr`, not `stdout`.  You can merge them with `2>&1` on the `dwdiff` command
- The output you want actually appears to be printed first by `dwdiff`, but you see a different order due to the two different outputs.  So you want `head` instead of `tail`
- You want 1 line, not 0

So try `dwdiff -s ... 2>&1 | head --lines=1`

```
 $ dwdiff -s /etc/motd /etc/issue 2>&1 | head --lines=1
old: 67 words  3 4% common  2 2% deleted  62 92% changed
```

Alternatively, if you want the `new` line instead of the old, and to simplify the ordering, try throwing away the diff output:

```
 $ dwdiff -s /etc/motd /etc/issue 2>&1 1>/dev/null | tail --lines=1
new: 5 words  3 60% common  0 0% inserted  2 40% changed
```

Note that the order of redirection is important:  First clone `stdout` into `stderr`, then redirect `stdout` to `/dev/null`.